# Can't decode a simple ARM function prototype from a dissasembly?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, reverse-engineering, ida

I can't figure out the prototype for this simple function:

**In stack:**
[image: stack screenshot]

**Function call:**

[image: function call screenshot]

That's what I got so far, and it causes an error.

```
//No idea
void CameraDeviceCreate(int one,int two,int* three);
```

There are three registers used (R0,R1,R2) so there should be three arguments. Third one refers to a stack variable (I still don't get how that works). #**0x28** (var_28) is only mentioned in the ADD call, not sure what it could be. *Where did I make a mistake?*

If I missed some info out tell me and I'll add it. This is from **Camera.framework** by the way.

Comment: This is WAY too little information for reverse engineering. I would think that Apple is likely to reject an app that links to a private interface.

Comment: What do you mean by "it causes an error"?  Do you have any information about what's in R4 and R5 when `CameraDeviceCreate()` is called?  Does R4 have something to do with `var_28`? It appears that R4 might be a pointer to a struct, and what's being passed to the function is a pointer to one of the struct's fields.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: never mind AppStore. @Michael Burr No I don't, and I can't attach a debugger to that application because gdb crashes. Besides I don't know how to use GDB beyond basic debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you have it wrong?

Note, there is no guarantee that the third parameter is 'int*' - you need to look at what is in R4 at that point - I would guess its actually some sort of structure being pointed at, rather than an int.

Comment: I think so, because my application crashes when the function is called.